# Where does linux kernel get available DRAM size

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, bootloader

I want to tweak available DRAM size when it passed to kernel side.

I have 8 GB RAM mounted on device and want to let Kernel know that it have only 4GB RAM without soldering 4GB memory on it.

Please let me know where to start.

1. The code where where LK passing memory information(DRAM start address and size) to the Kernel.
2. The code where LK recognize the DRAM size.

What I am trying to do is just change device tree file to have 4GB only.

```
from> (total 8GB)
    memory_0: memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
    };
    memory@880000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x00000008 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
    };
    memory@90000/0000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x00000009 0x00000000 0x80000000>;
    };
    memory@98000/0000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x00000009 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
    };



to> (total 4GB)
    memory_0: memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
    };
    memory@880000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x00000008 0x80000000 0x80000000>;
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: You can restrict the memory used by the kernel with a commandline parameter.

Comment: Architecture?  Consult the kernel documentation for Device Tree bindings, i.e. for definitions of the values in node properties.